# return bearer token with requests

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, header, bearer-token

So i have a spotify account gen and was wondering if theres a way to return the bearer token to the accounts once they are made. I tried looking at the request reponse and headers but there was no bearer token.

```
def gen(): 
  global accs
  global invalid
  currentuserfull = email()
  username = name()
  resp = requests.post("https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/signup/public/v1/account", data={
      "birth_day": "1",
      "birth_month": "01",
      "birth_year": "1970",
      "collect_personal_info": "undefined",
      "creation_flow": "",
      "creation_point": "https://www.spotify.com/uk/",
      "displayname": username,
      "username": username,
      "gender": "neutral",
      "iagree": "1",
      "key": "a1e486e2729f46d6bb368d6b2bcda326",
      "platform": "www",
      "referrer": "https://www.spotify.com/uk/",
      "send-email": "0",
      "thirdpartyemail": "0",
      "email": currentuserfull,
      "password": password,
      "password_repeat": password
  }, headers={
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "es-419,es;q=0.9",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
      "sec-gpc": "1",
      "referer": "https://www.spotify.com/",
      "referrer-policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  })
```

How can i get the bearer token the accounts i generate or is there a way to see the headers of requests being sent with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to see the headers of requests being sent with selenium

It's possible with *selenium-wire*.

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.spotify.com')
# authorize and perform some actions

#then
for request in driver.requests:
     print(request.headers['Authorization'])
```

- some error handling might be required here if some request doesn't have Authorization header. I've not checked the exact behavior.

In this way you'll be able to view any request/response header.

---

**Reference**

https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/

Comment: i tried selenium wire but for some reason it wont let me login to spotify with it

Comment: @jack12 this might be due to bot detection. Have you tried with `from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome`? See https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/ Bot Detection section.